# Is lodash _.map faster than Node.js map?

Tags: node.js, mapreduce, lodash

I have a project where I'm using `_.map` everywhere. Now I have the need to improve it's performance and was wondering if is there any time-performance benefit for using `_.map` instead of `[...].map`.

Answer (score 5):

Here are a comparation of the native map against the lodash map

Aparently lodash is faster

https://jsperf.com/native-map-vs-lodash-map

Comment: Agreed. Taking a look at the [lodash map implementation](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lodash/lodash/4.6.1/dist/lodash.js) (look for arrayMap, which is basically looping through each element and executing the callback each time), I don't see any faster way to execute that.

Comment: I ran the benchmark several times, native map was *always* faster than lodash on Chrome 80.0